# Why does the "Double" data type mess up my Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a program which gives me the index of the first 1000-digit number in the Fibonacci sequence. I have set the data type as "Double" because I need to store the long numbers, however the output I get isn't right?

I have tried setting the "num" data type as "integer", "long" and even "int64", but all these just give me an overflow error after about 2 seconds.

```
Dim num, prev, temp, index As Double
Sub Main()
    num = 1
    prev = 1
    temp = 1
    index = 1
    While Len(num) < 1000
        Console.WriteLine(num)
        temp = num
        num += prev
        prev = temp
        index += 1
    End While
Console.WriteLine(index) 
Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

I would expect the program to output the Fibonacci sequence until it finds the first 1000-digit number, and then it will output the index of it. However, I just get an output of loads of decimal numbers (to about 20 decimal points) and then it outputs 8. Forever.

I am truly stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: `Len(num)` gives the storage size for the `Double` type, which is 8 bytes, so your loop will never end. `Double` is [not going](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/double-data-type) to be able to store a 1000 digits number either. Have a look at [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=netframework-4.8) if you need that kind of thing.

Comment: Replace `Len(num)` with `CStr(num).Length` And as Gserg noted, th3re is no way a double Is gonna store a thousand digit long number.

Comment: I also wonder if the "8" it outputs forever is in fact `∞`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precision of a `double` data type does not allow you to store so many digits.

If you use `BigInteger` you can store as many digits as you can, as the data type grows its storage according to your needs.

Additionally, as suggested by the comments, a quick and dirty way to stop after 1000 digits is to have the number converted to string and check its length. This way you are not using mathematical operations which would result in an overflow.

Your code should look like the following:

```vb
   Dim num, prev, temp, index As BigInteger
   Sub Main()
       num = 1
       prev = 1
       temp = 1
       index = 1
       While BigInteger.Log10(num) <= 999
           Console.WriteLine(num)
           temp = num
           num += prev
           prev = temp
           index += 1
       End While
       Console.WriteLine(index) 
       Console.ReadLine()
   End Sub
```

Comment: `CStr()` doesn't work for the BigInteger type, so it would have to be `num.ToString().Length`, but using `BigInteger.Log10(num) <= 999` is noticeably faster (if the numbers aren't being printed).

Answer (score 1):

It all comes down to no data types in vb being able to hold a 1000 digit number. If I were you I would have an array with 1000 items and have each item be a digit.